# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: (using import OS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I looked around for solutions. One of them is to use os.path, but I still get an error. I'm trying to send an image to a discord server channel when the bot is up and running [here is the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=images#how-do-i-upload-an-image). But I get an error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Attached are some screenshots of my project, code, & error message.[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the path isn't complete. The dog.png are in the src folder so instead of using is, simply specify the directory yourself, **BASE_DIR = '.\Pickle Rick BOT\src'** . Then you can us os.path.join or simple string concatenation of f stream to join the **dog.png** part to this. The backward slashes should've double.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it looks like you're missing the 'src' folder.

`__file__` should get you your path. It should look like this:

```
C:\Users\David\Desktop\Nová složka\test.py
```

strip it of the file name, in this case `test.py`, and replace it with the file you want, for example:

```
C:\Users\David\Desktop\Nová složka\dog.jpg
```

In some cases you might have to replace the `\` with `\\` because of some sort of unicode error or something, I am not sure.